# tcsh & sed: no output

Tags: sed, tcsh

I’m trying to replace the 3rd column of a file for itself plus the value of column 2 (without any space). I get the proper value for variable c and a but then `sed` doesn't give any output. Any clue?

```
#!/bin/tcsh 
setenv c `cat lig_mod.pdb | awk '{print $3}'`
echo $c
setenv a  `cat lig_mod.pdb | awk '{print $3=$3$2}'`
echo $a
sed -i "" 's/^'"${c}"'$/^'"${a}"'$/g' lig_mod.pdb
```

Comment: That `sed` command is operating on the file in place (from `-i`). It also is matching against the value of `c` as a line by itself, is that what you want? It also will replace that line with `^<value-of-a>$`, which probably isn't what you intended.

Comment: if i replace -i for -e  (sed not in place) I also don't get any change in the file.

Comment: If you remove `-i` then `sed` won't change the file and will send it standard output. I couldn't tell if you were looking for standard output and not seeing it before so I threw that in. The major issue preventing the changes from working are that your pattern and replacement are both incorrect as I also indicated. `^` in the pattern matches the start of the line, not the start of a "word". Same for `$` at the end of the line.

Comment: Already removed that characters. Still no output

Comment: Do you mean "no output [to the screen]" or do you mean "no change to the file"? Can you show the values of `$c` and `$a` and the relevent lines from `lig_mod.pdb` that should be changing?

Comment: ATOM      1  N   LIG   900      37.835  44.362   4.538  0.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  N   LIG   900      35.545  44.377   4.983  0.00  0.00           N
ATOM      3  N   LIG   900      34.830  49.313   7.069  0.00  0.00           N
ATOM      4  N   LIG   900      34.946  40.990   2.513  0.00  0.00           N1+

Comment: I need $3=$3$2, thats the change I need, for each line. And the problem of using awk is that is space sensitive. Which is not going to work for me!

Comment: Put the values of `$c` and `$a` in the post so you can format them and indicate which is which. And you are already using `awk` you just aren't using it to make the change to the file because it doesn't operate in place. Also I'd expect that `$a` might not be the value you expect above since you are printing the result of the assignment to `$3` and not printing the line after assigning to `$3`. Does `awk '{$3=$3$2}7' lig_mod.pub` get the output you want?

Comment: Yes it gives the output I want. And the values are already there. $a=N N $b=N1 N3

Comment: If that awk command does what you want then just use `awk '{$3=$3$2}7' lig_mod.pub > lig_mod.pub.new` and then swap the files around if you want the original name.

Comment: The numbers after "900" as you can see in the example above can change, then the spaces change. Thats why I dont want awk.

Comment: I can't make sense of the data in the comment. That's why I told you to edit them into your post. And if that awk doesn't work why did you say it gave you the output you wanted?

Comment: awk works to define the varibales, but not to modify the file!

Comment: Why not? You are trying to replace the third value with the third + second value? Does the command `awk '{$3=$3$2}7' lig_mod.pub` display to your screen *exactly* the output you want for each line or not? If not, how not? What does it get wrong? Update your post with sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `awk` is usually better for columns parsing this one-liner `sed` can work for you as well:

```
sed -i 's/ \(\w*\) \(\w*\) / \1 \2\1 /1' lig_mod.pdb
```

the '/1' at the end denote the instance number you desire to change which for the 2nd and 3rd columns is the first, but you could use it for any adjacent columns.